# Does this inequality involving the sum of components of a vector and its norm have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

It's true that:
$$
\dfrac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \sqrt{2}
$$

Or, in perhaps a more useful form, for a vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
x_1+x_2 \leq \sqrt{2} \cdot \lVert x \rVert
$$

For $x,y>0$.
This can be seen in many ways, perhaps the most obvious of which is to use polar coordinates, where it reduces to $\sin\theta + \cos\theta \leq \sqrt{2}$.

It's slightly non-trivial, but appears to be useful when you want to force the norm of a vector to show up.

Does this have a name? Does it generalize to arbitrary vector spaces or dimension?

Comment: I don't know of a name, but you'll find the generalization to your inequality [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Properties). Indeed, it generalizes to any finite dimensional space.

Comment: This is a relation between the taxicab norm and the Euclidean one, and as has been pointed out, generalizes to $R^n$

Comment: It's called the extreme norm equivalence. I remember first  seeing it  in the work of an old lady mathematician Volzhvelskaya (who isn't very famous), but it's generalization, namely just norm equivalence on finite dimensional spaces, is credited to a whole lot of people.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality: $|x\cdot y|\leq \|x\|\cdot \|y\|$, for all $x,y$ in any number of dimensions.  This is a special case when each co-ordinate of $y$ is $1$.

Comment: One could say it's QM-AM inequality, which holds for any number of reals. It's easily put in the form:$$\frac{x+y}2\le \sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}2}$$